# Why is the ability red?

Tags: the-division-2

The following is a picture of my agent, looking at the mod inventory. It's clear that my Skill Power is 1335, yet the requirement for the mod is 352, and it's marked in red.

Does this mean that I do not meet the minimum requirements to use this mod?

[image: Agent with 1335 skill power and red requirement]

Comment: At first glance, it seems it's just because the item is of a higher level than your character level.

Comment: Did you check whether your stats are normalized for PvP or not?

Comment: @WoLfPwNeR Yes, I use normalized stats. I've found I can activate the mod ability, even when I don't meet the skill power requirement too. I think they might just be broken.

Comment: @DavidYell The abilities work just fine with mods that you don't meet the requirement for, the mods just don't apply to the abilities. I assume it's so that you can use some situational talent to boost your skill power high enough temporarily to make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarise the comments, there are two stats effecting the usage of skill mods.

- Current agent level
- Skill power score

You must be higher than both of these for the skill mods effect to be active. You are still able to slot the mod.

[Since the Invasion: Battle for D.C. - April 5th, 2019 release, skill mods have been updated](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/2032255-Patch-Notes-Invasion-Battle-for-D-C-April-5th-2019).

- Complete overhaul of skill mods to give more achievable requirements and more reasonable bonuses.

  - A closer equivalence between required skill power and the bonuses granted.
  - Changed the amount of skill power on gear to not increase exponentially with level, but instead more linearly. This results in most skill power values on gear being lower, but in accordance with the lowered requirements.
  - Tweaked the ranges of bonuses to be within acceptable bounds where they had extreme values before due to scaling errors. Most notably radius and ammo/charges values.
  - Players will see both the bonuses and the requirements of almost all skill mods change as a result of this overhaul.
  - In end game, both Superior and High-End skill mods exist to cover the different needs of different builds. They can overlap in power, but High-End mods have a higher maximum roll potential.
  - We are looking at ways to provide lower value/quality mods in end game world tiers in the future to provide a solution to the fact that on very low skill power builds, there would be room for those mods, and currently we are aware that means you have to save mods from your leveling experience.